# MySQL DESCRIBE INTO OUTFILE with windows command-prompt

Tags: mysql, cmd, command-prompt, file-io, describe

I want to print the structure of a table fomr my database. 
Now I use the mysql command:

```
DESCRIBE products;
```

But how do I get this output into a txt file? Like:

```
DESCRIBE products; > products.txt
```

Comment: Related, if it's of interest, I wrote a *Describe All Tables* in [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38679580).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql -u username -p -e 'DESCRIBE databasename.tablename' > output.txt
```

Comment: It should be double qoutes, Thanks